# Why iteration over bs4.element.ResultSet makes no copy of original?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, iteration

I am a bit confused by the behaviour of iteration on Beautifulsoup ResultSets. Generally speaking, in python I would expect iteration to generate a copy of each element. A list cannot be modified by assigning new values to iterated elements.

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
for elem in l1:
    elem = elem + 10
```

will not modify original list l1

But if I do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for elem in soup('body'):
    elem.unwrap()
```

Then the original soup element is modified!

This seems inconsistent to me, but it is clear I am missing some basic stuff here

I am using python 3.5 and BS 4.4.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was a beginner's mistake. When iterating over the soup elements, we are iterating over mutable elements so a modification of a component of a copy is still reflected onto the original variable

```
l1 = [[1,1],[2,2]]
for elem in l1:
    elem[1] = 5555
```

would deliver

```
l1 = [[1,5555],[2,5555]]
```

Same behaviour for the iteration on bs tags